# Block port(s) in Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, port

Is there any plugin that can set firefox to simulate port 8080 is blocked ?

I want to see how my website behave if certain ports (8080) is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a plugin that allowed you to do that, but I found a file change that does.

Go the *user.js* file and make the following change:

```
user_pref("network.security.ports.banned", "8080");
```

> Mozilla allows a user to modify the default port blocking through the addition of preferences containing comma delimited lists of port numbers to either the user.js file (for single users) file in the user's profile directory or the all.js file (for multi-user systems) in the defaults/pref/  sub-directory in the installation directory for Mozilla in order to enable or block ports in Mozilla.

[Source and further reading](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html)

Comment: You should be able to do that from about:prefrences too, if I recall.